# Segmentation fault error in bash script. no recursion

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault

Please help! I cannot figure out what is wrong with this bash script. It was running fine for a day, but now i keep getting a segmentation fault error everytime i run it. I'm not great with bash, so I don't really know what rules there are to break here, nor if I'm breaking them. I did look up the definition of recursion, though, and it seems I am not making any calls to this script within this script, so i think i'm safe there. (Please correct me if I'm wrong about that though)

```
#!/bin/sh

HTMLFILE=/var/www/vhosts/edu.critiqueit.com/tmp/convertdocs/test_doc.html
DOCXFILE=/var/www/vhosts/edu.critiqueit.com/tmp/convertdocs/test_doc.docx
LOCKFILE=/var/www/cron/convert_failed.lock
LOGFILE=/var/www/cron/convert_log.txt

if [ ! -e "$DOCXFILE" ]
then
    echo "[$(date)] Missing docx file. cannot perform safety check. killing script." >> "$LOGFILE"
    exit 1;
fi

if [ -e "$HTMLFILE" ]
then
    rm -rf "$HTMLFILE"
    echo "[$(date)] File exists. beginning conversion" >> "$LOGFILE"

    unoconv -f html "$DOCXFILE"
else
    if [ -e "$LOCKFILE" ]
    then
        rm -rf "$LOCKFILE"
        echo "[$(date)] Beginning conversion after server reboot" >> "$LOGFILE"

        unoconv -f html "$DOCXFILE"
    else
        touch "$LOCKFILE"
        echo "[$(date)] Conversion failed. restarting server." >> "$LOGFILE"

        /sbin/shutdown -r now
    fi
fi
```

Comment: What's the name of your script?  If you add an `echo "starting script"` at the top, do you see it getting called multiple times?  Are you sure your segfault isn't happening in one of the called programs like `unoconv`?

Comment: On the first line, add a space then "-xv" at the end and run it again. Then you will see each line go by as it is executed and be able to locate the fault.

Comment: it only echoes once. I am not positive that the error is not coming from unoconv. is there a way to tell? it seems like it's coming from the bash script though. here is the error: convert_test.sh: line 33: 11323 Segmentation fault      unoconv -f html "$DOCXFILE"

Comment: i added this to the top of the script and it still failed, and without printing any errors: #!/bin/sh -xv

Comment: How are you running it then?  If your command line looks like `sh path/to/script` then you need to change that to `sh -vx path/to/script`.  (But then the whole `#!/bin/sh` shebang is pointless.)

Comment: It seems almost certain that the problem is inside `unoconv`.  Does it need disk space for temp files etc. or something which has run out?

Comment: ah i see. well yes unoconv is quite a complex program. It is basically a shell to openoffice. Well, perhaps I will look into this.